# What does "_" mean before a variable name?

Tags: solidity, events, state-variable

I'm a beginner, just recently started reading the docs for Solidity.
I can't seem to find this anywhere on google. What does the underscore mean when placed with the `indexed` keyword?
Examples:
`_from`
`_id`
`_amount`
`_account`
How are these different from other variables, and how are they used in events?

Comment: Nothing special, just a coding convention. For example, you can decide to use it for every local local variable in your code. BTW, it is not recommended anywhere in the [Solidity Style Guide](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/style-guide.html#naming-conventions).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no meaning as far as Solidity is concerned.

Some programmers choose to use a leading underscore for all function parameters, just as a convention to indicate that they're function parameters.

They're also often used so as to avoid collisions, e.g.:

```
uint256 totalSupply;

constructor(uint256 _totalSupply) public {
    totalSupply = _totalSupply;
}
```

There, calling the parameter `totalSupply` would shadow the existing state variable `totalSupply`, so the leading underscore is used to avoid the naming collision.

Comment: Does this work for solidity 0.6.2?

Comment: yup. Its simply a convention ^

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a little more context, as stated by someone else in the comments you won't find any mention of the leading underscore in the styling guide.

You can however find a recommendation to use a trailing underscore to [avoid naming collision](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/style-guide.html#avoiding-naming-collisions).

> This convention is suggested when the desired name collides with that of an existing state variable, function, built-in or otherwise reserved name.

As to why it's being used in Solidity, as an example in Javascript the leading underscore is used as a convention to fake encapsulation and indicate that a specific name is protected.

In C# it indicates that [a field name is private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#C#).

So I guess there's a general tendency to use the leading underscore to indicate that a name is reserved for internal use only.